# Travis-ci.org stuck "Build created succesfully"

Tags: travis-ci

I've got a lot of queued Travis-ci.org jobs showing 'Build created successfully" but nothing is happening.  It looks like Travis has got itself into a look creating jobs for my last few commits and not processing any of them.  How can I clear out these jobs?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I really don't understand what a travis-ci.org 'request' is because the problem was a bad .travis.yml file and once I fixed that, the CI started again.  But the 'requests' are still there :-(.

The 'solution' was to install the travis command-line tool which includes 'travis lint' and allowed me to lint my .travis.yml file until it was at least happy.  The downside to this is that, on Windows at least, installing the travis tool took a lot of time and a lot of disk space as it instaled Ruby, MinGW and lots of other stuff that I will probably never use again!

But until travis-ci.org/com creates an on-line linter (how hard can it be?), that's what we're stuck with.  OTOH, the first step of the travis-ci.org/com build could be to lint the file and complain if it fails - just a suggestion :-).

Comment: Turns out that you do NOT need the entire travis command line.  The linter works as follows:

- Reads the .travis.yml as a YAML file and throws errors if it is not valid (generic) YAML

- POSTs the YAML to the travis-ci.org website (https://api.travis-ci.org/lint) where it gets linted against the Travis-CI 'YAML schema'

- Returns a JSON edited response indicating warnings, errors etc.

So you can do all this very easily using a Python script and requests.

Comment: Having figured out how Travice linting actually worked, I wrote a little Python script to avoid having to install the entire Travis envionment: https://github.com/papadeltasierra/travislint